# Mozilla Firefox & Internet Explorer compatible clipboard in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox, clipboard

I need to copy a text from a textbox into the clipboard with ASP.NET. I want a code that is comparable with Mozilla Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer clipboard copy is trivial:

```
// set the clipboard
var x = 'Whatever you want on the clipboard';
window.clipboardData.setData('Text',x);

// get the clipboard data
window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
```

Firefox, not trivial at all. Impossible actually with pure JS unless you have signed scripts etc. There is a workaround using a Flash object, however. Read about it [here](http://www.jeffothy.com/weblog/clipboard-copy/)

Answer (score 0):

For non-IE browsers use this common-all-over-the-world-used script. Google for "_clipboard.swf" file. (though, this code will NOT work on newest Flash 10 becouse of security reasons)

var flashcopier = 'flashcopier';

```
     if(!document.getElementById(flashcopier)) {
        var divholder = document.createElement('div');
        divholder.id = flashcopier;
        document.body.appendChild(divholder);
     }

     document.getElementById(flashcopier).innerHTML = '';
     var divinfo = '<embed src="_clipboard.swf" FlashVars="clipboard='+encodeURIComponent('YOUR_VALUE_FOR_CLIPBOARD')+'" width="0" height="0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>';
     document.getElementById(flashcopier).innerHTML = divinfo;
```